# Calculate the expectation of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, independence

Let $A$ be a $d\times d$ non-negative definite matrix. Let $\{{\bf{u}}_i\}_{i=1}^{n+1}$ be i.i.d. random vectors sampled uniformly at random from the unit sphere $\mathbb S^{d-1}\subset \mathbb R^d$.

Define $Q_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \sum_{i=1}^n \textbf{u}_i^T A \textbf{u}_{i+1}.$

I want to calculate the expectations $\mathbb E[Q_n]$ and $\mathbb E[(Q_n)^2]$ in terms of $n,d, (a_{i,j})_{1\leq i,j \leq d}$. But I don't know how to proceed.

---

My attempt:

The pdf of every $\textbf{u}_i$ shall be $f_{\textbf{u}_i}(x_1,x_2,...,x_d)= \frac{1}{B}$ for all $(x_1,...,x_d) \in \mathbb S^{d-1}$ and equals zero otherwise, where $B$ is the area of $\mathbb S^{d-1}$. We may write $\textbf{u}_i$ as $(u_{i,1}, u_{i,2}, ..., u_{i,d})$ and $Q_n$ shall be a sum of terms of the form $u_{i,j} a_{j,k} u_{i+1,k}$ over $i,j,k$, where $1\leq i,j,k \leq d$.

We know $\{\textbf{u}_i\}_{i=1}^{n+1}$ is i.i.d. Can we conclude that $u_{i,j}$ and $u_{i+1,k}$ are independent, for all $i,j,k$ with $1\leq i,j,k \leq d$? (If it is true, can you give me a reference on this inference?) If they are really independent, then $\mathbb E[Q_n]=0$.

In the expression of $(Q_n)^2$, there will be terms like $u_{i,j} a_{j,k} u_{i+1,k} u_{i',j'} a_{j',k'} u_{i'+1,k'}$ for $1\leq i, i', j, j', k, k' \leq d$.

I don't know how to calculate $\mathbb E[u_{i,j} u_{i+1,k} u_{i',j'}u_{i'+1,k'}]$. Thanks for help.

Comment: The $u_i$ do not have a probability density function, as $\mathbb S^{d-1}$ is a $\lambda^d$ null-set.

Comment: @SmallDeviation Alright, maybe we shall "restrict" $f_{\textbf{u}_i}(x_1,x_2,...,x_d)$ on $\mathbb S^{d-1}$. Now $\textbf{u}_i$ has the pdf mentioned in the attempt.

Comment: Sure, just keep in mind that this will be a density w.r.t. the surface measure on $\mathbb S^{d-1}$, **not** with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the distribution of the $u_i$' s is invariant by rotation, without loss generality one may assume that $A=\mathrm{diag}(c_1,\ldots,c_d).$ Clearly $E(u_i)=0$ and therefore $E(Q_n)=\sum_{i=1}^nE(u_i)AE(u_{i+1})=0.$ Now
$$Q_n^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}E((u_iDu_{i+1})^2)+2\sum_{i<j}^{n}E((u_iDu_{i+1})\times u_jDu_{j+1}))=V+W$$ Clearly again $E(W)=0$ since $i<j$ implies that $u_i$ and $u_{j+1}$ are independent. Clearly also $E(V)=nE((u_1Du_{2})^2).$ For simplification write $u_1=(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$ and $u_2=(y_1,\ldots,d_d)$. We get
using independence of $u_1$ and $u_2$ and the fact that $E(x_i)=E(y_j)=0$
$$E(V)=n \sum_ {k=1}^dE((x_kc_ky_k)^2)+2n \sum_ {k<m}E(x_kc_ky_k)\times (x_mc_my_m))=n \sum_ {k=1}^dE((x_kc_ky_k)^2).$$

We are left with the calculation of $$E((x_1c_1y_1)^2)=c_1^2(E(x_1^2))^2.$$
Since $x_1^2+\cdots+x_d^2=1$ we have $E(x_1^2)=1/d.$ Finally
$$E(Q_n^2)=\frac{n}{d^2}(c_1^2+\cdots+c_d^2)=\frac{n}{d^2}\mathrm{trace}\, A^2.$$

Comment: Thanks Letac. I have a question about one step. How do we derive $E(x_1^2)=1/d$ from $x_1^2+ ... + x_d^2=1$? I guess you implicitly use that $E(x_1^2)=E(x_2^2)= ... = E(x_d^2)$, which how do we prove? Besides this question, there may be some possible typos. I guess it shall be $\color{red}{E(}Q_n^2\color{red}{)}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}E((u_i\color{red}{A}u_{i+1})^2)+2\sum_{i<j}^{n}E((u_i\color{red}{A}u_{i+1})\times u_j\color{red}{A}u_{j+1}))=\color{red}{E(}V\color{red}{)}+\color{red}{E(}W\color{red}{)}$.

Comment: Oh! plenty of typos indeed, thanks for the corrections. For a rigorous proof of $E(x_1^2)=E(x_2^2)$ you use the fact that the distribution of $ u=(x_1,\cdots,x_d)$ is invariant by the orthogonal group $\mathbb{O}(d).$ And the linear transformation $u\mapsto (x_2,x_1,x_3,\ldots,x_d)$ is after all an element of $\mathbb{O}(d).$

Comment: Hi Letac, sorry for this late comment. After carefully calculating the whole process on my own, I found a question. Every non-negative definite matrix is congruent to a diagonalized matrix, but it may not be similar to a diagonalized matrix. Similar matrices have the same trace, but congruent matrices may not have the same trace. Therefore, if we denote the matrix after diagonalization by $A’$, then trace$(A)$ may not be equal to trace$(A’)$. And, trace$(A^2)$ may not be equal to trace$([A’]^2)$. Shall we not do diagonalization for $A$ at the very beginning? Thanks.

Comment: For a symmetric matrix $A$, the diagonalization is done  with orthogonal matrices. Hence if $A=U^TDU$ then trace $A$=trace $DUU^T$=trace $D$ since $UU^T=I_n$

Comment: Sorry for another late reply. I have been thinking this problem for quite long. Yes you are right, but I still have a question. If we didn't do the diagonalization at first, then our matrix $A$ is not diagonal, and we end up with calculating $E[\sum_{j,k} (x_j A_{j,k} y_k)^2]$. And finally, we have $E(Q_n^2)=\frac{n}{d^2} \sum_{j,k} A_{j,k}^2 \neq \frac{n}{d^2} \text{trace }A^2$. Why wouldn't we have the same answer? Did I make any mistake in the calculation? Thanks Letac!

Comment: Trace$(A^2)=\sum_{ij}A_{ij}^2$since $A$ is symmetric.